# Re initialize flickity after replace html

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, flickity

I need to replace entire html with new html.

I want re-initialize [flickity plugin](http://flickity.metafizzy.co) after replace html and thus don't apply to replaced.

I tried this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xv0437n/)
(in jsfiddle click on button `Initialize flickity` and see result)

Comment: It works if you init the new gallery with $('.gallery').flickity(); instead of $carousel.flickity(); Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/920mu6fh/